# ''.velocity is not a function - Materialize css

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I have a problem with Materialize CSS. With many things that use Javascript I get the error: 'x'.velocity is not a function.

For example: when I click the collapse icon for the sidenav I get e.velocity is not a function. And with the modal I get the error: g.velocity is not found.

I use Materialize CSS in combination with Laravel and installed it this way:

```
npm install materialize-css
```

Some things work fine like the wave effect when I click a button. So I know that the javascript is working fine.

I hope somebody can help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have node.js

Answer (score 0):

To solve this is used the jquery version that is located in the materialize folder

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('materialize-css/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
require('materialize-css');
```